# Should I use Nitrobolon for better muscles growth?

Tags: muscle-gain, supplements, creatine

I've been searching about nitrobolone, but I found only shop pages. Is nitrobolon(technutrition) realy can help me improve my work out and improve muscles strength and growth? Is it better than creatine?

Comment: Are you familiar with supplements or fairly novice?

Comment: Quite novice. Never used this

Comment: Be leary of any supplement claims.  There are very few that actually work as advertised.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's a combo Nitric Oxide + Creatine supplement.

Nitric Oxide is coming from the arginine and citrulline. Glutamine is for digestion. Creatine does creatine things (increases water retention in muscles).

Nitric Oxide gives a pretty good pump but the pump is temporary. If it allowed you to press your workouts further you could develop more muscle. Creatine is the same idea. It can allow for your muscle to be worked more; which means more muscle growth. Supplements do nothing on their own. They only allow you to, maybe, workout longer and harder. If you're inexperienced I would recommend against getting into too many supplements. My personal downside to Nitric Oxide is that since it is a vasodilator it has a similar effect, to me, as Viagra.

Personally, I'd just buy a normal Creatine supplement. It's way cheaper than what you've linked. Get your diet and workout plan in line before you get too heavy into supplements.